# diff between variable and property?

Tags: c#, variables, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between a field and a property in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c)

i would like to know the difference between a variable and a property.can any one explain

Comment: Do you mean `Difference between Field and Property`?

Comment: How about reading a basic C# book?

Comment: You might want to look at the following blog which is explaining differences between properties and variables: [Jeff's blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/properties-vs-public-variables.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply you can't validate the data being stored in variable but in a Property you can.
A Propery is more like a method as it has `get` & `set` methods which you define to handle the data.

Also they are usefull in Databinding.

Properties expose fields. Fields should (almost always) be kept private to a class and accessed via get and set properties. Properties provide a level of abstraction allowing you to change the fields while not affecting the external way they are accessed by the things that use your class.

---

### Example:

like in  case of **Date of Birth**. You need to validate that age is less then todays date:

In a Field this is valid:

```
DateTime age = new DateTime(2012,12,1);//1 december 2012
```

But in a property you can validate it:

```
private DateTime _dob;
public DateTime dob
{
    get
    {
        if(_dob!= null) return _dob;
    }
    set
    {
        if(DateTime.Compare(value, DateTime.Today) <= 0)
        {
             _dob= value;
        }
        else
        {
               throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Date of Birth should be less then today's date");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A property is actually a special function with a get method and a set method. The get and set methods can provide some logic, like validation that a field can not.

You can back your property with a private field, like this

```
private int age;

public int Age
{
    get { return age; }
    set
    {
        if (value < 0)
             throw new ArgumentException("Must be > 0");
        age = value;
    }
}
```

You can also implement only the get part and calculate the result

```
private int a;
private int b;

public int Sum
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: ok.thanks .provide some examples for validation

Answer (score 2):

A property or "auto property" is just an easier way to write the complete implementation. It's a way to make code more readable and more manageable.

A `field` in C# inside your class outside of methods might look like this:

`private object _obj;`

However if you want to "expose" this to other classes that uses your class you don't just want to make it `public`. Because that would not give you any control over what values it is set to.

Therefore you might want to have a `getter` and a `setter` for this particular `field`.

One way to implement this, and a quite common way in most other languages is to have two methods:

**Getter**

`public object getObj() { return _obj; }`

**Setter**

`public void setObj(object value) { _obj = value; }`

However doing this for all of your `fields` makes a lot of lines that you wouldn't really need, this is a trivial problem and therefore C# will help you out by giving you a way of defining "properties".

**Properties in C# 1.0**

In C# 1.0 you wrote a property like this:

```
private object _obj;
public object Obj
{
    get { return _obj; }
    set { _obj = value; }
}
```

You still needed the `private field` though, which is still an overhead.

**Properties in C# 2.0 and onwards**

In later versions of C# you could make it easier for yourself, in C# 2.0 you could write something like this:

`public object Obj { get; set; }`

Which would auto-generate the above in your `IL` which in the end would end up looking the same as the first example when using methods.

In C# 3.0 an issue was solved, how do you create a public getter but a private setter?

Nowdays you can write it like this:

`public object Obj { get; private set; }`

Which will let you expose the object, but make it read only! ( not true read only since you can manipulate it inside your class ).

So simply explained, a field is a variable exposed inside or outside your class, but you have no way of controlling the values that someone with direct access to it decides to set it to.

A property is a way to expose setters / getters to your fields, making it easier to manage input / output to and from your field.